# Convergence of product of almost everywhere convergent and in measure convergent sequences $f_{n}(x)p_{n}(x)$

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose we know that $a.e. \lim f_{n}(x) = f(x)$  and $\mu \lim p_{n}(x) = p(x)$, where $f(x)$ and $p(x)$ are bounded functions and $x\in X \subset R$. I was wondering whether we can say the following or no - $$a.e. \lim f_{n}(x)p_{n}(x) = f(x)p(x).$$

For sure we can say the above for convergence in measure. But what about convergence almost everywhere?

I'm sorry if something stupid.

Comment: If this were true, then setting $f_n(x)=f(x)\equiv 1$ we would conclude that convergence in measure  implies convergence almost everywhere. Does that sound plausible?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Maybe I stated my question somehow vague. What I mean, is in which cases we could conclude almost everywhere convergence? (somehow, like domination of $f_{n}(x)$ over $p_{n}(x)$.). What I'm really interested in, is the case where $f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f_n$ converges to zero almost everywhere, in order to conclude that $p_n f_n$
also converges to zero almost everywhere, you will probably also need to assume that 
 the sequence $p_n$ is bounded.

Here is an example to show what can go wrong, if $p_n$ converges in measure
but is not bounded.

We are working on $[0,1)$ equipped with Lebesgue measure.
Let's start with the typewriter sequence: For $k\geq 0$ we
define  for $2^k \leq n<2^{k+1}$ the indicator functions
$$t_n={\bf 1}{\left[{n-2^k\over 2^k}, {n-2^k+1\over 2^k}\right)}.$$ To paraphrase 
Example 4 at [Terry Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/), this is a sequence of indicator
 functions of intervals of decreasing length, marching across the unit interval 
over and over again. So $t_n$ converges to zero in measure, but not pointwise
 almost everywhere.

Now if $p_n=nt_n$,  then $p_n\to 0$ in measure. 
If  $f_n=t_n/n$, then 
$f_n\to 0$ pointwise, but $f_n p_n=t_n$ does not converge pointwise.

Comment: Thank you, very very very much. It was very helpful.

Comment: Glad to help out!